# Best practices to design some specific react components, like notification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

There are three way people to use components like notification/toast in React:

In [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#usage), there are a [modal example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/yzMaBd) which is similar with notification like this:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
    ...
}

class App extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isOpen ? <Modal>...</Modal> : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In Material-UI, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export default class SnackbarExampleSimple extends React.Component {
  ...
  handleRequestClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Snackbar
          open={this.state.open}
          message="Event added to your calendar"
          autoHideDuration={4000}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And in Ant Design:

```
import { message, Button } from 'antd';

const info = () => {
  message.info('This is a normal message');
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Button type="primary" onClick={info}>Display normal message</Button>
, mountNode);
```

Clearly, the third way is the easiest way for user to use, so why React docs and Material-UI implement this type of components like that? Is it easier to implement or maybe just more "React" way? Or other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a subjective one and also your 3 examples are all a little bit different. From my experience (developing in React and Material-UI for about 1 year), the biggest gains that you get from your vanilla React and Material-UI examples is **reusability and composability.**

In the first example, you can take that Modal class that you defined and, if it is exported, you can reuse it anywhere in your application and just pass it down different dynamic props to change its content or appearance.

In the second example with Material UI it is the same thing except you are provided the component and a set of predefined properties to act on it.

I have not used Ant Design personally but it looks like the example you gave is not doing anything different, but merely showing/explaining its rendering in the top-most location of your React application. Both of your other 2 examples (`Modal` component and the `Snackbar` component) could be rendered on the `ReactDOM.render()` level as well, it's just that those docs have chosen to put them in a more realistic position deeper in a theoretical application.

Hope this helps!